# Is it possible to check if an array has all values are true, some are true and all are false

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I'm having an array `[true,true,true,false,false]` is it possible to check if the array has all values true or some values true or all values false in a single loop to increase performance. Currently I'm using `every()` and `some()` for every action

Just trying to know if there is a cleaner approach than checking twice.

Comment: `s = new Set([true,true,true,false,false])` - if `s.size` is two, you have a mix, otherwise `a.has(true)` will tell you if it is all true or all false

Comment: ^ignore the typos ... it's `s.has(true)` of course

Comment: surely though you only need a .some for true and a .some for false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
const s = new Set(arr);
const mixed = s.size === 2;
const allTrue = !mixed && s.has(true);
const allFalse = !mixed && !allTrue;
```

however, more performant in my simple testing, by a factor of about 8x (at least in firefox), is

```
const hasTrue = arr.some(v => v);
const hasFalse = arr.some(v => !v);
const mixed = hasTrue && hasFalse;
const allTrue = !mixed && hasTrue;
const allFalse = !mixed && hasFalse;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming everything in `arr` is a boolean, you could do something like:

```js
const arr = [true, true, true, false, false];

const hasTrue = arr.includes(true);
const hasFalse = arr.includes(false);

const mixed = hasTrue && hasFalse;
const allTrue = hasTrue && !hasFalse;
const allFalse = !hasTrue && hasFalse;
```

Comment: @Bravo I suspect not for the `true` case - it will still scan the array until it finds a `true` value, which could require scanning the entire array.

Comment: surprisingly ... `arr.includes` is slower than `array.some` (firefox at least)

Answer (score 1):

> Note this solution is not particularly performant in JS and @Bravo's answer is a better choice.

You could use [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) on the array; if the result is different you have both, if the result is the same then dependent on whether the result is 0 or 1 they are all `false` or all `true` respectively. For example,

```js
const arr = [true, false, false]

const min = Math.min(...arr), max = Math.max(...arr);

const mix = min != max;
const alltrue = !mix && !!min;
const allfalse = !mix && !min;

console.log(mix, alltrue, allfalse);
```

Comment: that works .... until your array has a length > 500000 (in firefox) :p

Comment: Well, in that case they can always use your solution! :) just out of curiosity did you compare this solution when you did performance testing?

Comment: No, I did not - did you want me to :p

Comment: using Math.max/min is an order of magnitude slower than using some/includes (at 500000 length) - even slower than using the Set method

Comment: @Bravo binary or decimal?

Comment: huh? 10(decimal) times slower :p

Comment: @Bravo I do a lot of work in binary... but 10x slower is bad. I'll add a note (and an upvote to you) to direct people to your answer.

Comment: 340ms for 500000 records is nothing though